# Buffer amplifier for DC-1MHz (discrete parts)

Tags: transistors, amplifier, dc

I would like to make a buffer amplifier from discrete parts (transistors) which is working from DC to 1MHz. I'm not able to google any schematic or tutorial or app note etc.

Everything I found was for AC only (it has blocking capacitors in the input and output).
I know how this amplifier works:
[image]
I made couple of them for audio related signals.

Is there anything similar but starting from DC (0 Hz)?

I know I could use single opamp:
[image]

but I really would like to play with discrete parts (and learn along the way), and simulate it in spice.

Comment: Simply eliminating C1 and C3 will trivially make it DC coupled. You need to think about the DC gains and offset voltages on input and output but it will pass DC and have gain. Opamps simplify things, that's all.

Comment: You need differential pairs for DC, though I think there is a way to do it with biasing but it has a lot of drawbacks. It's not a very good way to do it and fairly arduous I believe since you have to "micromanage" each stage's coupling to the next.

Comment: @DKNguyen well, the schematic I provided is just for explanation. I'm not insisting to use or tweak it. I just do not know what kind of circuit should be used to provide buffering from 0 Hz.

Comment: I know. The circuit used nowadays is the differential long tail pair, (found in opamps). Look up an opamp internal circuit. The other way which I have never seen or heard of in actual use is Brian's method where you meticulously chain CE amps together without AC block caps.

Comment: I do know that when DC-coupling a chain of amplifiers, it helps to alternate between N and P type devices since it helps keep the offset in check rather than continuosly accumulating after every stage.